# Two to four day backpacking trip in Washington State for May

Tags: backpacking

I am looking for a backpacking trip somewhere between two and four days long in Washington State that is possible to do under current conditions (May). Any recommendations?

Comment: The question is too localized. Rather, it should be asked how generally locate trail maps and information for a specific season, latitude, etc.

Answer (score 1):

I just notices the submit date for this is a month ago, so it's probably too late, but the Pasayten Wilderness in North Central Washington is beautiful. 
http://www.wilderness.net/NWPS/wildView?WID=445

Comment: Well there is always another May coming. Is there any particular trail/hike you can recommend in this area?

Comment: I did a 50 mile loop through there with my scout troop and remember that it was beautiful. Alas that was a long time ago (15 yrs) and I don't remember the specifics. Sorry :(

Comment: The Pasayten is a beautiful area, well worth visiting, but much of it will still be under snow in May in a typical year.

Answer (score 1):

The Ozette triangle is a great 1-3 night backpacking trip in the northwest tip of the state. I went in May and it was spectacular with very few other people about. However, it is slippery on the cedar planks that make up the first third of trail when it's raining (which it was that day).

http://www.wta.org/go-hiking/hikes/lake-ozette/