# What overnight backpacking trails are clear of deep snow now (or likely to be in the next two weeks) in northwest Washington?

Tags: hiking, backpacking, united-states, snow, spring

I am looking for an overnight backpacking trip to do in the next few weeks somewhere in western Washington. But I am worried about deep snow remaining on the trails.  Based on last winter's snowpack, the rate of melting this spring, and on prior knowledge of the trails in that area, can anyone here suggest a trail or trails, or even a local area, that would have good hiking conditions and possibly, although not necessarily, a few places snow-free places to camp?  For example, should I be looking at places below N feet in altitude?

Comment: This is basically asking for product recommendations and we should close this https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/questions/4082/two-to-four-day-backpacking-trip-in-washington-state-for-may?rq=1

Comment: @Charlie Brumbaugh I don't see how this is a price/shopping question.  The OP Is asking about trails that are not impassable because of snow.  He is not asking about commercial trips.  As for the Q that you linked to, I don't see how that is opinion based, as people who know the area will know the snow conditions and the trail conditions -- factually, based on info about the snow pack and how it is melting.

Comment: You may have better luck [here](http://bpbasecamp.freeforums.net/board/33/pacific-northwest)

Comment: @ab2 this question is very broad and shows a lack of any research.  The area is mountainous and snow falls year round in some areas.  Additionally if it is not snowing it is probably raining.  Some areas have 300+ days of rain per year. Going on an overnight hike, requires checking the weather, and still being prepared for snow.  Lastly the question asks for "best" which is an opinion, in this case, there is no best that is snow proof.

Comment: @James Jenkins Please look at the edited question.

Comment: @ab2 That makes it MUCH better, less broad, and more answerable. I am not the person who can answer it, but I think it can be answered now.

Comment: Agreed - thanks for taking the time and effort to edit!

Comment: @JamesJenkins Weather forecasts tell you nothing about the snow on the ground.  I have been hiking on the nearby mountain for some weeks now--the forecast has caused a couple of cancelled hikes, it says nothing about the snow-blocked trails that have caused more hikes to be called short.  (By now the trails would normally be completely clear.)

Answer (score 4):

This forum is worldwide, you're not going to get a good localized answer.  I do have two suggestions, though:

1)  Look at local hiking groups.  I suspect you have Meetup groups, there might be others, also.  See where they are scheduling hikes, and see what people are saying about past events.  There is no substitute for eyeballs on the trails.  (Just yesterday we got a surprise.  We were on a loop that doesn't have a lot of elevation change.  The first 4 miles have little shade, we saw the occasional mass of snow in shady spots off the trail.  The last two have a lot more shade--and even those of us with poles and microspikes decided it was unsafe to continue.)

2)  Ask the rangers in the area(s) you are considering what the conditions are.  It's unlikely they have eyeballed everything but plenty of hikers will let them know about problems they found on the trails so they will have a reasonable picture of the trail conditions in their area.